# Storing inputText values when "jumping" from one controller to another

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have the following mask/view:

[image: input mask]

After entering the name and description, I can add a list of existing attributes by clicking on "Add existing" button.
This opens another mask/view, where I can select from a list of existing attibutes. This (new) mask/view has it's own controller and model too.

When I'm finished with the selection, I have another button that bring me back to this mask.

The problem is that when I come back the name and description fields are empty.
This happens because when I click the "Add existing button" the controller/model of this mask is not called and the values are not stored.

How can avoid this and have the values stored?

Thank you for any help
Francesco

Comment: JSF 1.x or 2.x? Component libraries?

Comment: JSF 2.0 and standard/core components

Answer (score 1):

This only works if the new view is inside the same view. E.g. when it's an overlay dialog which is presented by a hidden `<div>` and not a plain `window.open()` popup window. This way the beans will have access to each other and you will be able to execute ajax updates instead of submitting/refreshing the entire page.

This is pretty complex to homegrow if you're not that familiar with HTML/CSS/JS. I suggest to look at a component library which offers such a component like [RichFaces' `<rich:popupPanel>`](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky) and [PrimeFaces' `<p:dialog>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialog.jsf).

Comment: Thank you BalusC for your answer. What do you think about this: I though I could do the redirect inside the apply request phase. When I click the "Add existing" button, I set a flag and make the page reload so that the values are stored in the model. In the listener I catch the apply request phase and I check for the flag and do the redirect. Do you think would it work? (keep in mind I'm quite new with JSF, so excuse me if I tell bull@@it ;) ) –

Comment: Something like this: `public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event)
  {

    System.out.println("After Phase->" + event.getPhaseId());
    ExternalContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    if ("createRedirect".equalsIgnoreCase(ctx.getRequestParameterMap().get("mode")))
    {
      try
      {
        
        ctx.redirect("businessObjectAttributeSpecificationListView.xhtml");
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: There are indeed ways like you proposed, but this is plain clumsy. I really recommend an overlay div. It's then so much easier to just wire the beans in each other as managed property without fiddling with request parameters or even the session scope and remembering the already-entered data.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in session or conversation bean.
Session bean approach have huge drawback when user works in multiple tabs/windows - he uses only one session bean, so he overwrites what he did in other windows.

Conversation scoped bean solves this. But conversation scope was not in javaEE 5, its in CDI (part of EE6).